# C# Force ListBox to update elements

Tags: c#, user-controls, listbox

I'm subclassing the standard ListBox control. I get notified of changes to any of the elements added to the list. The task is to update the text shown by the ListBox for the changing element.

I'm aware that i could just remove the changed element and add it again, but this seems not preferable for obvious reasons.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How do I make a ListBox refresh its item text?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/61421/how-do-i-make-a-listbox-refresh-its-item-text)

Comment: Not only is this a duplicate of the question mentioned above — the other question has much better answers, too.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Unfortunately, the data-binding in `ListView` doesn't support regular (item) change notification events (`FooChanged` / `INotifyPropertyChanged`). However, if you know about the change, you can get the list to re-bind itself. Since you are subclassing, you can call:

```
this.RefreshItems();
```

or for a single item:

```
this.RefreshItem(index);
```

Otherwise, since this isn't public, you can simulate it by changing the `DisplayMember`:

```
lb.DisplayMember = "";
lb.DisplayMember = "Bar";
```

A little hacky, maybe, but it works, and maintains the current selection etc (unlike clearing the `DataSource`).

Comment: Thanks man. I looks like 'a little hacky' methods work better than documented methods in MS Windows.

Answer (score 1):

Why don't you manually update Text of an item in question? You might also consider rolling out your own databinding mechanism for ListBox. And check out [ObjectListView](http://objectlistview.sourceforge.net/html/index.htm) to see if it's of any help.

Comment: The ListBox does not care about changed ToStrings of the elements displayed. Invalidate fails, too. Will have a look at ObjectListView, seems interesting. :)