# How refresh items of a ListBox?

Tags: c#, winforms, listbox

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [C# Force ListBox to update elements](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/519538/c-sharp-force-listbox-to-update-elements)

Let's consider this small piece of code:

```
listbox.DataSource = base_items;
listbox.DisplayMember = "Name";
// ... a bit later in the program
base_items.Add(  new Base_Item("Unnamed")  );
```

From this point, how do I do to make the listbox update its items? The only way for me to see the update is to close the window and reload it again.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Just remove and add databinding again.
You can create method that can be used on first load and when new item was added:

```
    void BindData()
    {
        listBox.DataSource = null;
        listBox.DataSource = base_items;
        listbox.DisplayMember = "Name";
    }
```

So here is the code for adding new item and refreshing listbox:

```
    base_items.Add(new Base_Item("Unnamed"));
    BindData();
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, it works :D I should have thought about making it null...

Answer (score 8):

As mentioned in Marc G's answer.

[C# Force ListBox to update elements](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/519538/c-sharp-force-listbox-to-update-elements)

If you know that the list needs refreshing, simple update the `DisplayMember` of the listbox.

```
listbox.DisplayMember = "";
listbox.DisplayMember = "Name";
```

Comment: wow, strange approach but effective.