# How do you select an item in a combobox and have it populate a listbox from an already created file?

Tags: c#

I'm doing a project for class and I'm stuck on this part, I'm using Visual Studios 2017 RC.

Comment: share your code so, it can be refined.

Answer (score 0):

You're a little vague there so I hope this is what you mean:

combobox.SelectedItem will give you the display value of whatever item is selected in a combobox.

listbox.Item.Add(itemToAdd) will add that item to your listbox. You'll have to rebind the listbox if it is already created. You'll need to rebind the listbox after you do this for the item to actually show.

See this link for a simple way to do that: [How refresh items of a ListBox?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13998587/how-refresh-items-of-a-listbox)

Comment: I'm not exactly sure how to be more specific about it I apologize. I'm trying to select an item from the combobox so that a series of subclasses of the item selected appear within the listbox, and I'm told to do this by pulling that information from a file into the listbox. Is there some way to do that using "listbox.Item.Add(itemToAdd)?"

Comment: I think I understand. You want to change what items are populated in the listbox based on the selection of the combobox?

If so, you could use a switch statement.

    switch(combobox.SelectedItem)
    {
        case "option1":
             listbox.Item.Add(Item1)
             listbox.Item.Add(Item2)
             //etc...
             break;
        case "option2":
             listbox.Item.Add(Item1a)
             listbox.Item.Add(Item2a)
             //etc...
             break;
    }