# When does .NET's ListControl update its text from ToString() of its members?

Tags: .net, object, listcontrol

I have a class which can change the value it returns in ToString(), but the ListBox which contains instances of this class in Items.

The ListBox doesn't show this change unless I add or remove some item to the ListBox which is when refreshes the list, how can I make it refresh the list myself?

Comment: Post your current code and perhaps someone here can see the issue.

Comment: I have a class called Foo and an instance called foo. I add foo to the ListBox. foo initally returns "123" from ToString(). The value that foo.ToString() returns is a variable that I changed through user input to "abc". So now foo.ToString() returns "abc" but the ListBox still shows one item, "123". 

Now I add another item to the ListBox and suddenly the first item (foo) has changed from "123" to "abc".

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/61421/how-do-i-make-a-listbox-refresh-its-item-text

Comment: Thanks, I should have searched harder :)